# Stream live video to Facebook from iOS

Tags: facebook, live-streaming

I’m using Live video API, i want to show privacy (Public, Friends, only me) before streaming live video on Facebook from iOS app.

1 Does FBSDKShareKit supports live video content ?

2 Can i retrieve friend list and display privacy in custom views ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Facebook live api requires publish_video permission, which has been deprecated. How can we live stream now ? I have also created a question for this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431997/how-to-live-stream-with-fbsdksharekit

Answer (score 2):

I've made the [facebook-live-ios](https://github.com/hansemannn/facebook-live-ios) Swift library last week that provides you an Facebook-SDK-like interface for configuring, starting and stopping Facebook Live sessions in your own iOS app. Give it a try!

Comment: is this code working : https://github.com/hansemannn/facebook-live-ios working properly? i m getting errors.